# How to safely upgrade node.js from 5.9.1 to 6.14.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, v8

Our entire application is written in node 5.9.1 and now time has come when we need to upgrade to a version that supports ES6. I am planning to upgrade to at least version 6.14.0 that supports 99% of the ES6 stuff. I am embarrassed to say that we don't really have a good test coverage of our code and it makes me scared to upgrade. 
Has someone upgraded from 5.9.1 to ~6 and can shed some light on the compatibility?
I am concerned about certain stuff breaking after the upgrade.

Comment: read here ... for any major changes https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#commits-38  E.g.,  `(SEMVER-MAJOR) crypto, string_bytes: treat buffer str as utf8`  is a pretty big one, so if your library was a crypto package that only supported node <= 5 and now you're supporting 6+ then you need to ensure its okay to treat buffer str as utf8... but ultimately upgrading an app is really vague and we can't give a whole lot of guidance.

Answer (score 2):

id suggest you upgrade to latest lts and then deal with whatever breaks by writing tests around the broken area and fixing them, then continuing to write tests whenever you work on a new area. That way when you upgrade your tests will tell you if anything breaks..

I would be surprised if this update actually broke anything for you though.